# Javascript sidebar onClick events without HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working with a WYSIWYG editor that auto-generates code in js. I've created a sidebar but cant figure out how to create onClick events for each item in the sidebar as there is no way to access the HTML.

Below is sample code that gets triggered when clicking on an item on the sidebar which basically produces a toast message with the menu item name and its index value and then closes the sidebar.

How would I get the sidebar items to display a different page or element instead?

```
if (app.sidebar.item.subindex !== undefined) {
  alert('You clicked the ' + app.sidebar.item.text + ' item, with index: ' + app.sidebar.item.index + ' and the subindex: ' + app.sidebar.item.subindex);
} else {
  alert('You clicked the ' + app.sidebar.item.text + ' item, with index: ' + app.sidebar.item.index);
}

app.hideSidebar();
```

Comment: you can use event delegation, add the click event listener to `body` and look for click on your item `e.target == app.sidebar.item` then do what you want

Comment: Actually I just noticed that the above code is in the onClick event. How then would I change it baring in mind the it's an array I think

Comment: Create please example on jsfiddle or somewhere else to speed up the process, your question is very abstract without code